# for loop and function in R for

Tags: r, statistics

I am totally new to R and don't know much. I would really appreciate if someone can help me to solve it. It's my second day trying to use different codes for this problem but can not get any answer. I know there are some other questions related to this. I have checked each and everyone but still can not understand. Please don't mark it as a duplicate and provide with an answer. I would really be thankful.

So basically i have to create a function ans(n)which returns a vector with the n first numbers of the Fibonacci sequence as elements.

I know the fibonacci. so for this first i created a vactor as:

```
x<-c(1, 1)
```

Then i used this command:

```
 ans<-function(n){
 for(i in x){
 return(x[n-1]+x[n-2])
 }}
```

Where i am going wrong?

Comment: A function returns only one value, so only the first iteration of for loop is returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store values in your vector before returning it.

```
x = c(1, 1)

ans <- function(n) {
    for(i in 3:n) {
        x = c(x, x[i-1]+x[i-2])
    }
    return(x)
}
```

Output :

```
ans(9)
[1]  1  1  2  3  5  8 13 21 34
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Though answer is correct, still i want to understand the code:

Comment: so first we created vector i.e. x then we create function , why do we need to write 3:n and why we have started the expression with c(x, ....) why not just start with x[i-1]?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `for` loop, the definition of the Fibbonacci sequence lends itself particularly well to a recursive function implementation.

```
# Calculate Fibbonacci term x
fib.x <- function(x) {
    if (x <= 1) return(x) else  return(fib.x(x - 1) + fib.x(x - 2))
}

# Return the Fibbonacci sequence of length n
fib <- function(n) sapply(1:n, fib.x)

fib(9)
#[1]  1  1  2  3  5  8 13 21 34
```

You can make this [even faster by using `Rcpp`](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/fibonacci-sequence/).